# How to prevent css style or its selector * from applying to specific elements

Tags: html, css

I am making a embed-able widget for the customers so that they can embed my service on their own website. 
I am having one issue that if customer is using bootstrap v3.3.7 (tested only this version so far) on their website so one of its css style:

```
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box; }
```

is destroying my app alignment.

My widget app without Bootstrap:

[image: My widget app without Boos]

My widget app with Bootstrap:

[image]

I have tried a lot of things like I applied internal and inline css styles to override it but nothing worked.

I tried this:

```
 #widgetParent {
                    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                    line-height: normal;
                    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
                    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
                    box-sizing: content-box;
                }
```

Here I applied property value "content-box" because its fixing the issue on Google Chrome Dev Tool but its working in inline or internal css.

I even tried to adjust my app the Bootstrap styles in a way that it will look better but its not possible because obviously not everybody use Bootstrap so my app alignment will crash on without Bootstrap websites.

So, Is there any way I can detect whether the website has Bootstrap or not so I can give styles according to it or any way to prevent this * selector from applying to my widget app ? If anybody have any solution to it please let me know.

**Note:** 
I have tested this on bootstrap v3.3.7 CDN which is included in the app like this :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Thank You

Comment: Try `!important`.

Comment: Could you perhaps post a working snippet of your HTML/CSS code that we can see your exact layout, this way we can help you as there's not enough information here.

Comment: Honestly I'd make your whole widget work with `box-sizing: border-box`. If this is not an option you could try to override it with `#widgetId * {box-sizing: content-box;}``

Comment: The * selector has a 0,0,0,0 specificity. It's unlikely the problem comes from this.

Comment: better if you'd include a snippet of your code.

Comment: @MikeRodham actually there is no css file I have because its a widget so I will have to do everything inline or internal for css as far I think. And because I am using React so no one HTML file

Comment: @soueuls I didn't understand what actually you mean by this. Can you explain a bit ?

Comment: @A.Khan The CSS cascading algorithm utilizes an x.x.x.x pattern which stands for 1. inline style, 2. id selectors, 3. class selectors, 4. element selectors. !important takes precedence over all. The * selector is special because it's specificity is 0.0.0.0 meaning everything will take precedence over it.

Comment: okay got it. by the way my problem is resolved thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this in my internal css I mean the html style tag and the problem resolved.

```
 #widgetParent div {
                    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
                    line-height: normal;
                    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box!important;
                    -moz-box-sizing: content-box!important;
                    box-sizing: content-box!important;

                }
```

Thanks everyone for help.